# MySQL - Is there a way I can get the other columns of a row which got the MAX value

Tags: php, mysql, max

I have this MySQL query that can get the maximum value from all rows in my table, it's working though but the problem is how can I get the other columns from the row that has the maximum value?
The `record_id` that shows in the result is from the first row not from the row that has the maximum value.

Query:

```
SELECT `record_id`, MAX(download_count) as `max_dl` FROM `downloads`
```

Result:

```
+-----------+--------+
| record_id | max_dl |
+-----------+--------+
|        13 |      5 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: `SELECT record_id, download_count as max_dl ORDER BY download_count  DESC LIMIT 1` to get `record_id` of row where `download_count` is max.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(record_id) as record_id, MAX(download_count) as max_dl` highest `record_id` and highest `download_count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to list all the records with the maximum value:

```
 SELECT 'record_id', download_count as 'max_dl' FROM 'downloads' WHERE download_count = (SELECT MAX(download_count) FROM 'downloads')
```